# How do I encourage users to click on a button without making it too distracting?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons

I'm a back-end programmer with very little knowledge about UI/UX.

I'm implementing a button on a website. Clicking on it will show something like an Easter egg. There will also be other buttons and some content on the page.

My goals are two:

- It shouldn't distract someone who is in hurry.
- Make casual visitor (who are not in hurry), want to click it

How can I do this? In other words, what do we know about UI principles for making an interface element *appealing* without making it *distracting*?

Note: I earlier checked the spotlight feature. It seems to be very distracting for users who are in hurry.

Comment: As written, I'd argue that we can't be of any real help. What you're asking does not have a singular answer, especially with the context you've provided here. There are multiple ways to draw a user's attention and encourage them to take an action... but *how* to do that depends greatly on specific elements of the content at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the "advanced features" panel in the controls for [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) Version 1:

[image: Alfred setting button reading "Do not press this button"]

It's not intrusive, but anyone who's reading through the page will be tempted to click on it!

In general, here are some questions to consider:

- Where in the user flow does the opportunity to click the button appear?
- Which users do you want to avoid distracting with it? What do you know about where they go on your site / what features they use?
- Which users do you want to see it? What do you expect them to be doing at the time?
- How much does the easter egg take users off-track / disrupt what they were trying to do? If it's minimally disruptive, maybe you could link it to some other behavior such as opening the settings or spending a certain amount of time on the homepage.

---

PS - The button takes the user to a video about the [marshmallow experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_marshmallow_experiment).

Answer (score 4):

I think a more inviting interaction should be not just a simple button :)

I suggest that you use some kind of a slider element with a funny micro copy...
Or if you have the time, create a rotating knob that goes up to 11.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsWPKT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Commendable attributes of Easter Egg UI:

**Subtlety**

**Minimalism**

**Discretion**

**Nuance**

I considered the above deeply, and this came to mind:

[image]

Comment: To be honest, it looks more like an ad to me. I feel I'm very less likely to click on it

Comment: I had to vote this up, not because it's right (which clearly isn't), but because it's funny and a nice joke :)

Comment: Your April fools joke is 2 days late. Now it's just a bad answer, sorry.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I find the question far funnier than your answer.

Comment: Everyone knows that "Warning: do not press this button" is the appropriate label for a red button!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to work this out. If you don't want the user to be very much attracted to the button, choose a color for the button which is a bit more darker (say 5% - 10%) to the color of the background color that you have chosen. Sites like [this](http://www.0to255.com/) will help you with that. In other way, you could solve this as @dimshik has proposed which would be kind of cool and good for your target audience. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

To encourage user to click on your button, Use some **highlighting colors** suppose if your website is in Blue color, then use Orange color in order to gain users attention.

- Use creative labels for you buttons like for Sign Up button you can use "Why don't you join for fun?"
- Use Animation ([LIKE THIS](https://www.google.com/partners/#a_home;bdgt=30000,150000;lang=en))
- Its good approch if you place it somewhere in left hand side of website.
- Accompany action with an image.